# Python - how to add character to a string if that character doesn't exist already?

Tags: python, string

I want to add a character to string only if that character does not exist in a specific position of the string.

I want to do this using Python. It does not matter where the string is coming from.

In my specific case, the string contains an embedded code for a video (iframe).

Here is an example of the initial string, without the question mark:

`<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I want to check if the src URL contains a question mark (?) at end and, if not add it. The end result would then be:

`<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXX?" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I hope it's clear enough. If not, feel free to ask.

Thanks!

[EDIT] - I answered myself below.

Comment: What do you mean by "using Python"? Is this generated from a Python server-side framework? If you want to do this on the client side you'll need Javascript.

Comment: I meant I want to do this on the server side, using Python.

Comment: so which framework are you using? Where are you getting the value of the `src` attribute from? Can you share some actual code?

Comment: That is the actual code. I really just want to see if '?' exists in the iframe string - if not, add it to the end of the url.

Comment: Really? Why the down votes? It's a simple question O_o

Comment: "That is the actual code" - but it's not Python code, it's just HTML. And you asked for a way to do this "using Python". Without seeing the actual (Python) code we can't really help. As for the downvotes - I haven't downvoted, but I can understand them because your question doesn't really make sense, and your subsequent comments haven't helped explain.

Comment: I really don't know where you thought I was being sarcastic. I genuinely didn't understand the context behind the question, and was trying to get some clarity. It now appears you were merely trying to do some string manipulation with Python, and the fact that the strings happened to be HTML was irrelevant - I apologise that this was not clear to me. I'm glad you found the answer you needed and sorry that I wasn't able to help myself - but I was genuinely trying to understand the issue, and the attitude you've displayed in your last comment was not one which will encourage people to help you.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I would like my question to be taken out of "on hold". I think the question is clearer now but, if not, feel free to edit it or suggest a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited] I ended up finding a solution:

```
import re
data = '<iframe src="http://ddsdgfdf/video/87987987" something lalala="0"></iframe>'
m = re.search(r'src="(.*?)"', data)
str1 = m.group(1)
if not str1.endswith('?'):
    str1 = str1+'?'
result = re.sub(m.group(1), str1, data)
print(result)
```

Comment: Added suggestion by Brice to look for the character at the end of the string instead of anywhere on the string.

Answer (score 2):

Python strings have `.endswith()` method which you could use to detect if the "?" exists or not.

In your case, I would first use a regex to isolate the src parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can by slicing and concatenating.

Suppose you have a string

```
name = "Inut"
nname = name [0:2:1] + 'p' + name [2:4:1]
print (nname)
```

Note: Here slicing works as following:

`variable [start:stop:jump]`

I hope this will work.

Comment: I edited your answer for the sake of clarity. FYI you can style multiline text as code by indenting it 4 spaces. You can stile a single line as code by wrapping it in single quotes `

Comment: Actually I am new in this site as well as I am not in front of my computer. So I could't indent those well.

Comment: This is helpful for adding the character but I would still need to find the correct indexes. I was looking for a solution to do both things.

Comment: Everything just like string indexing just some difference in "stop" section. For stop section you have to count as usual like 1 2 3 4 not 0 1 2 3 4. That's it. If you still not understand let me know.